# functional equation $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy
> $f(x^{2024}-2023f(y))=f^{2024}(x)-2022y-f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$

I'm starting to learn about functional equations and it seems that this problem is quite difficult for newbies like me. I don't have any bright ideas, please give me suggestions, thank you very much.

Comment: Does $f^{2024}(x)$ mean $f(x)^{2024}$ or $f$ composed with itself $2024$ times?

Comment: Please edit the title to be more descriptive of your problem.

Comment: @aqualubix oh sorry my foul,it mean f(x)^2024

Comment: @whpowell96 sry,I will learn from experience

Comment: One of the first things to do is see what happens if you set $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ or if there is some $a$ with $f(a) = 0$, and you set $x = a$ or $y = a$. These four cases can reveal a lot about possible functions.